# Why is the list updated even when it is passed by value?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, output, singly-linked-list

```
public class Node<T> {
    T data;
    Node<T> next;
    Node(T data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}


public  class LinkedListUse{

    public static void print(Node<Integer> head){
        Node<Integer> temp = head;
    
        while(temp != null){
            System.out.print(temp.data +" ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    public static void increment(Node<Integer> head){
        Node<Integer> temp = head;
        while(temp != null){
            temp.data++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
    
        Node<Integer> node1 = new Node<Integer>(10);
        Node<Integer> node2 = new Node<Integer>(20);
        node1.next = node2;
        increment(node1);
        print(node1);
    }
}
```

Since `node1` has been passed by value (and not pass by reference) in the function `increment`, hence the output should be 10 20 according to me, but the solution is 11 21.

Can you please help me out with the explanation behind this

Comment: In Java, everything is passed by value, but what value is passed? In case of objects is the reference. So it's obvious that object properties can be altered when having the reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Very general advice: This kind of question is usually solved by placing intermediate output from the program. Add `System.out.println(...)` in the middle of the code to see what is happening.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: if the confusion is about the exact nature of passing a reference by nature, then that will only deepen the confusion. They must attempt to fix their misunderstanding of what passing a reference by nature is (and the duplicate question has some great answers that can help with that).

Answer (score 0):

The call to `increment` will mutate the list. Maybe it helps to visualise the list. After the execution of `node1.next = node2` we get this situation:

```
 node1           node2
  ↓               ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 10  │   │ data: 20  │
│ next: ──────> │ next: null│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

Then `increment(node1)` will define two more variables that reference `node1`:

```
 head
 temp 
 node1           node2
  ↓               ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 10  │   │ data: 20  │
│ next: ──────> │ next: null│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

In its `while` loop it will first increment `temp.data` (so it becomes 11), and then move the `temp` reference to `node2`:

```
 head            temp 
 node1           node2
  ↓               ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 11  │   │ data: 20  │
│ next: ──────> │ next: null│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

In the second iteration the `data` of `node2` (= `temp`) will be incremented, and `temp` moves to `temp.next` which is `null`:

```
 head                             temp==null 
 node1           node2
  ↓               ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 11  │   │ data: 21  │
│ next: ──────> │ next: null│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

So, although the changes to `temp` do not affect the reference of `node1`, any mutation to the *referenced nodes* will remain, even after the call to `increment` has finished execution. There is nowhere a value of 10 any more, nor 20. These have been overwritten.

When the `print` method is called, a similar thing happens as when `increment` was called, except that now no mutation is brought to the nodes. It will find the nodes as they were left by the call to `increment`. There are no other nodes.